# if preg_match with multiple words

Tags: php

Is it possible to use an if statement with `preg_match` for multiple words and to make the condition true if all words are found?

```
    $line = "one blah, two blah blah three";

    //not working code

    if (preg_match('[one|two|three]' , $line)) {
        echo "matched all three";
    }
    else{
        echo "didn't match all three";
    }
```

Have tried quite a few things but the conditional is always meet if even one word is found..

Comment: you want to do a http://php.net/str_replace with all charicters that you don't want to show up for the client

Comment: "|" means "or" - so you are correct when any of those words are found the condition is true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using positive lookahead:

```
preg_match("%(?=.*one)(?=.*two)(?=.*three)%", $line)
```

**EDIT:** Explanation: `(?=...)` says "match 0-length here if `...` is immediately following". Thus, you can sketch it like this (with a bit different original line to demonstrate the out-of-order bit):

```
two blah, one blah blah three
----------=== found!
=== found!
------------------------===== found!
```

(where `---` is `.*`, and `===` is the sought word). As each lookahead matches, the matched position is advanced by match size - but match size of a lookahead is always 0, so it stays in place (at the start of the string) and allows for the next lookahead to search the same space again.

Comment: but that requires them to be in that order, meaning they cannot be in different orders ie two cannot be before one?

Comment: @Jobst: It does not. The fixed-order regexp is much simpler: `one.*two.*three`.

Comment: @Amadan: How? curious!

Answer (score 3):

It might be more logical and efficient to use `strpos` instead to check if a string contains words, like so

```
$line = "one blah, two blah blah three";

if (strpos($line, "one") !== false &&
    strpos($line, "two") !== false &&
    strpos($line, "three") !== false) {
    echo "matched all three";
}
else
{
    echo "didn't match all three";
}
```

[Example](http://3v4l.org/vmKEr)

Comment: Three different checks.

Comment: I agree though that this is probably more readable than the regexp solution. Whether it is more efficient or not, I'll leave it to whoever wants to benchmark it. :)